# Residues of analytic operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, operator-theory

Suppose we have analytic operators $P_{z}: C^1[0,1]\to C^1[0,1]$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and the spectrum of $P_{z_0}$ possesses an isolated eigenvalue $1$ (assuming multiplicity is 1 and $I-P_z$ near $z_0$ is invertible). Consequently, there exists a finite-rank operator $P$, and for any $h \in C^1[0,1]$ and any $z$ near $z_0$, the following relationship holds:
$$[(I-P_{z})^{-1}h](0)=\frac{P(h)(0)}{z-z_0}+ \text{ analytic terms.}$$
Is there an effective approach to compute the residue $P(h)(0)$ solely from the information provided by $P_z$ and $h$?

Comment: There seem to be some assumptions missing. Under the given assumptions there doesn't need to exist such a projection $P$. In fact, $I-P_z$ need not even be invertible for $z$ close to $z_0$. (By the way, you probably want to replace $1$ with $\lambda$, but this doesn't fix the aforementioned issues.)

Comment: From the way the question is written, it is not so clear what you are after. According to the question, $h$ is arbitrary, so it is not clear what information it could give you about the residue. If all you know is the approximate value of $z_0$, then you could use any of the usual  [iterative eigenvalue/eigenvector approximation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms). Also, as noted in the other comment, perhaps you meant to write $z_0$ for the eigenvalue, or set $z_0=1$.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but the edit still does not give the existence of the finite-rank map $P$, since $z \mapsto I - P_z$ could have an essential singularity at $z_0$. To get the map $P$ one also needs $I - P_{z_0}$ to be a Fredholm operator (or equivalently - as one has invertibility close to $z_0$ - a semi-Fredholm operator).